# Postal address on website different from physical location

Tags: seo, local-seo, address

I'm doing local SEO for a friend's photography business to get experience. I'm currently working on citations, and also I've made sure her GMB listing is up to date and verified.

For all of the above, I'm using the same physical business address. However, she insists on also having PO Box address listed on her website, because this is her postal address.

Will this inconsistency cause issues? I don't feel it fits into the category of multiple business locations all.

Is there any way to resolve this so she can display a postal address, whilst signalling the physical address with consistency for all SEO purposes?

FYI the postal address is not the same one used to register her business, nor is the physical location (which is her photography studio).

Comment: These addresses should all align. It is okay to use the P.O. Box for a mail to address, however, Google does not take seriously any business that does not allow a walk-up address. I have that same problem with my rentals business. I do not want walk-ups. I want some privacy. Same for my antiques events business. Our business are the events and not a M-F, 9-5. However, any address that is close, such as a P.O. Box on the same street then that should be okay. I advise if your friend allows walk-ups, use the real address with a mail to address. This is perfectly normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NAP:**

Just ensure you got consistent Name, Address & Phone everywhere including Google local as well as other places.

**Address:**

You should keep the same address on the website which is used in GMB.

**PO BOX:**

If needed, you can also keep this in contact us as alternate address and it should be fine. If you are too concern you can place it as an image. PO Box address just should be limited for post purpose, as far as GMB is concerned it has no meaning.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, some companies are located abroad, but they have a mailing address in the USA or EU countries. So, there is nothing wrong with placing a physical address on a website. My company works tightly with one company that provides different translation services. They had two mailing addresses, one in London, UK, and another one in Toronto. Meanwhile, the company itself with its employees were located in some other country, I have no idea where exactly. You can recommend your friend to try this service https://ipostal1.com/virtual-office.php. Probably they can help her, but it won’t be for free. They charge approximately $10 per month for their services.